# How to ignore specific unused wires in Verilog?

Tags: warnings, verilog

I have certain wires and ports in my design which are intentionally unused, but which I want to keep.
How can I tell my Xilinx Verilog synthesizer to avoid giving "unused" warnings about those specific wires?

Apparently VHDL has an `open` keyword for this, but I don't know what its equivalent in Verilog is.

Comment: FYI, there is no such thing as a 'warning' in the verilog language. What you're seeing, and any solution, will be specific to the synthesis tool (Xilinx, in your case). May help you refine your search.

Answer (score 4):

Connect them to dummy wires and apply `(* keep="soft" *)` to those wires.
*(The names of the wires don't matter.)*

### Example

```
(* keep="soft" *)
wire [7:0] unconnected_received_data;

uart_receive uart_receive (
    .RST(RST), 
    .CLK(CLK), 
    .RXD(UART_RXD),
    .DATA(unconnected_received_data), 
    .RXD_READY(rxd_ready)
);
```

**This example will generate no warnings.**

---

### [Xilinx Constraints Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx13_4/cgd.pdf) on `(* keep="soft" *)`:

> As a result, the net is preserved during synthesis, but implementation
>   tools are given all freedom to handle it. Conceptually, you are
>   specifying a KEEP=TRUE for synthesis only, but a KEEP=FALSE for
>   implementation tools.

Answer (score 3):

I know how to get rid of these: `Port VALUE is not connected to this instance`

This appears to generate no warning with Xilinx tools, even though the VALUE output is not used:

```
counter #(5'b11010) counter_txd_en(
    .CLK(CLK),
    .RST(RST),
    .MAXED(step),
    .EN(1'b1),
    .VALUE()
);
```

I know that this solution is only a partial answer to your question, because it only covers unused ports.

Also if the unused port results in unneeded stuff in the submodule, you may get warning about those...

Answer (score 1):

As Tim said these warnings are tool specific and while you may be able to turn off the warning entirely you will not (commonly) be able to turn off specific instances of the warning.

That said you can get rid of them using the following method which I will state up front I think you should *not* use and simple live with the warnings.

So.  To get rid of these unused warnings the solution is to... use them!  i.e. gather up the whole mess into a wired-or, push the result to a top level output, and then put a timing ignore on that output.  That will take care of the unused warnings while also not effecting any PAR results.

Again, I'd recommend to not actually do this.  Warnings are there for a reason.  I assure you sometime in the future you're underlying assumptions will change and those warnings will become valid.

Comment: "Warnings are there for a reason." Yes, but sometimes it's the wrong reason. For example, if pipelining a 32-bit bus and then I only subsequently look at 7 of the 32 bits in the pipelined version, there's no reason for me to rewrite the code to pass *explicitly* only those 7 bits. It makes the code uglier and less readable, and besides, I would later probably need more of the bits as time goes on. But as long as I don't, the warnings just get in my way by adding too much noise.